# Persistent Installation Issues with Debian on SSD, Multiple Reinstalls and Hardware Changes

Tags: linux, debian, nvidia, ssd

Laptop: Asus ROG G751JY
I've been facing some persistent installation issues while trying to set up Debian on my laptop with both an HDD and an SSD. Here's a summary of what I've experienced:

1. Initially, I wanted to replace Ubuntu with Debian, but I accidentally installed Debian onto the HDD instead of the SSD. (Everything worked fine)
2. 1 Day later, After realizing the mistake, I attempted to install Debian on the SSD.
3. However, the booting process started taking unusually long, and eventually, the system failed to boot.
4. I tried to boot in rescue mode, which somewhat worked, but I encountered various complaints.
5. When I tried to log in under Wayland, Xorg sent me back to the login screen.
6. My Wi-Fi was also broken during this time.
7. In an attempt to resolve the issues, I reinstalled Debian, but this time, Wi-Fi started working for some reason. However, the package manager was broken due to libc6 dependency issues.
8. On the third reinstall, I used the default installer (not the live installer), which miraculously fixed both Wi-Fi and the package manager.
9. I proceeded to install Nvidia drivers after running nvidia-detect.
10. After restarting the system, it failed to boot and resulted in a kernel panic.
11. Repeated attempts in rescue mode also failed with kernel panic issues.
12. Frustrated, I wiped both the HDD and SSD and reinstalled Debian on the SSD twice, using both the KDE live and net installer versions.
13. Unfortunately, the system broke each time.
14. I tried switching to an MBR partition table from GPT.
15. Despite these efforts, I could not achieve a working Debian installation on the SSD.
16. As a last resort, I reinstalled Debian on the HDD, and this time everything worked instantly. The Nvidia drivers didn't cause issues, and both apt and Wi-Fi were functioning correctly.

I'm quite puzzled by these repeated failures on the SSD and would appreciate any insights into why this might be happening. Is there something specific about Debian, SSDs, or my hardware that could be causing these problems? Thank you in advance for any guidance you can provide.

Comment: This is very weird, my Debian install works flawlessly on the SSD. Maybe your SSD is dying? Without logs we can't help, just speculate.